# How to add scrollbar to text widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How to add scrollbar to text widget if text-widget inside top-level widget and added to layout via grid geometry manager.

I mean i got this inside "toplevel" window/dialog:

```
ttk.Label(toplevel,text="Text Area").grid(row=8,sticky=E)
self.TextAreaCCOrder=Text(toplevel,height=10,width=50 ).grid(row=8,column=1)
```

PS: I'm noob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that creates a frame with a scrollbar and a text widget:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the text and scrollbar widgets
        text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")

        # connect them to each other
        text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        vsb.configure(command=text.yview)

        # use grid to arrange the widgets (though pack is simpler if
        # you only have a single scrollbar)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # configure grid such that the cell containing the text
        # widget grows and shrinks with the window
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = Example(parent=root)
    frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer also answered another question i got but did not ask :)